# Unable to Install Specific JAX jaxlib GPU version

Tags: installation, gpu, failed-installation, jax

I'm trying to install a particular version of `jaxlib` to work with my CUDA and cuDNN versions. Following the README, I'm trying

`pip install --upgrade jax jaxlib==0.1.52+cuda101 -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_releases.html`

This returns the following error:

`ERROR: Requested jaxlib==0.1.52+cuda101 from https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/cuda101/jaxlib-0.1.52%2Bcuda101-cp37-none-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl has different version in metadata: '0.1.52'`

Does anyone know what causes this or how to get around the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error appears to be from a new check in pip version 20.3.X and higher, likely related to the new dependency resolver. I can reproduce this error with pip version 20.3.3, but the package installs correctly with pip version 20.2.4.

The easiest way to proceed would probably be to first downgrade pip; i.e.

```
pip install pip==20.2.4
```

and then proceed with your jaxlib install.

Comment: would you recommend conda-forge as a good way to install JAX?

Comment: For CPU, that might work. But I don't think conda-forge currently provides GPU-compatible jaxlib builds.

Answer (score 3):

Note that both the versions of jax and jaxlib has to match. You can use something like:

```
$ pip install --upgrade jax==0.3.2 jaxlib==0.3.2+cuda11.cudnn82 -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_releases.html
```

---

Another workaround would be to first choose a [specific version of jax and jaxlib from the available wheel files and then install those](https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_releases.html).

```
$ pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/cuda11/jaxlib-0.1.76+cuda11.cudnn82-cp39-none-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to change the link to:
https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html.
So, `pip install --upgrade jax jaxlib==0.1.52+cuda101 -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html`

Comment: Using wheel link from https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html worked for me: pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/cuda11/jaxlib-0.3.15+cuda11.cudnn82-cp38-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl